# Comparing values in two pandas dataframes within a maximum deviation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes:

```py
df_func = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_ref': [1, 4],
    'value1': [12.0, 13.1], 'value2': [55.1, 22.1],
    'value3': [22.2, 10.0], 'value4': [111, 0],
})

df_val = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col_ref': [4, 1], 'value': [13.1, 1.0]}
)
```

And 4 variables `max_deviation_value1` `max_deviation_value2` `max_deviation_value3` `max_deviation_value4` containing the maximum deviation allowed for each column in `df_func`.

For example, say:

```py
max_deviation_value1 = 1.5
max_deviation_value2 = 2
max_deviation_value3 = 4
max_deviation_value4 = 2.3
```

How can I compare each row in `df_val`'s `value` column with its corresponding values for all columns in `df_func` when `col_ref` is the same and check if the deviation is within the corresponding acceptable maximum deviation value?

Obs.: while `col_ref` is the common link between rows of the two DataFrames, it is not necessarily in the same order.

Comment: please provide an easily copy/pastable minimal reproducible example (as dataframe constructor)? right now the `|` make it hard to copy and you did not provide the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to make sure that `col_ref` is the index of each DataFrame, in order to make the rest of the operations easier.  If that isn't already the case, then:

```py
df_func = df_func.set_index('col_ref')
df_val = df_val.set_index('col_ref')
```

Then, we need to indicate to pandas that we mean to subtract `df_val's` `'value'` row-wise (from each column `value{i}`):

```py
diff = df_func.subtract(df_val.squeeze(), axis=0)

>>> diff
         value1  value2  value3  value4
col_ref                                
1          11.0    54.1    21.2   110.0
4           0.0     9.0    -3.1   -13.1
```

Now, on the `max_deviation` values: the simplest is to put them in a Series. For example:

```py
max_deviation = pd.Series(dict(
    value1=1.5,
    value2=2.0,
    value3=4.0,
    value4=2.3,
))
```

Then, the comparison practically writes itself:

```py
>>> diff.abs() <= max_deviation
         value1  value2  value3  value4
col_ref                                
1         False   False   False   False
4          True   False    True   False
```

**Addendum**

In the comments, the OP mentioned that there could be duplicate `col_ref` values in `df_func`. In that case, the following logic can be applied:

```py
# for example: duplicate col_ref == 1 in df_func
df_func = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_ref': [1, 4, 1],
    'value1': [12.0, 13.1, 5.0],
    'value2': [55.1, 22.1, 5.1],
    'value3': [22.2, 10.0, 2.2],
    'value4': [111, 0, 11],
}).set_index('col_ref')
```

Then, the following will correctly remove `df_val` `value' for each corresponding` col_ref` rows, no matter how many of them there are:

```py
diff = df_func - df_val.reindex(df_func.index).values

>>> diff
         value1  value2  value3  value4
col_ref                                
1          11.0    54.1    21.2   110.0
4           0.0     9.0    -3.1   -13.1
1           4.0     4.1     1.2    10.0

>>> diff.abs() <= max_deviation
         value1  value2  value3  value4
col_ref                                
1         False   False   False   False
4          True   False    True   False
1         False   False    True   False
```

**Last note**

If `df_val` **also** contains duplicate entries for `col_ref`, then we can deduplicate (e.g. taking the first one):

```py
# if done after `col_ref` has already been made the index
df_val = df_val.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='col_ref', keep='first').set_index('col_ref')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very well explained and looks quite efficient. I am trying to apply it to my scenario but in "diff = df_func.subtract(df_val.squeeze(), axis=0)" the dataframe diff has as columns "index, col_ref, value, value1,value2,value3,value4" where "index" is a increasing sequence starting in 0, col_ref seems correct and all other columns have NaN. Any idea on what might be happening?

Comment: Yes, make sure `col_ref` is indeed the index for both `df`s. I modified my original answer when I saw your note that "Obs.: `col_ref` is the index (...)". My initial answer had that "the first step is to get `col_ref` as index to make the rest of the operations easier".

Comment: good point. I considered it the index because it's the only common point between the dataframes, but the link is a bit more loose I'm afraid. How can I ensure the indexes are working and set?

Comment: I see. Let me modify both your question (that I modified to explicitly make `col_ref` the index) and my answer...

Comment: Ok, done.......

Comment: Thanks! tested here and it seems there might be some trouble with my data.. error is "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis". It fails in "diff = df_func.subtract(df_val.squeeze(), axis=0)". Could it be duplicated values in col_ref?

Comment: Yes. The logic is unclear if there are duplicate values `col_ref` -- what should it do?

Comment: For duplicate entries in col_ref the first entry found can be considered and the others ignored.

Comment: You should probably edit your question to illustrate the fact that `df_func` (or `df_val`? or both?) can contain duplicate `col_ref` values. Also, you should specify what the expected outcome should be. I could see a valid case where `df_func` could have duplicate col_refs, as long as `df_val` is unique wrt `col_ref`. But in any case, please be as specific as possible, and what outcomes you'd like.

Comment: Makes sense. As your answer does address my original question considering the information provided in it, I will select it as Accepted. Apologies for the unclear situation and thanks for the answer!

Comment: you're welcome; see also the addendum in my modified answer.